# Instagram stories and local videos play in slow motion but sound is fine

Tags: video

A friend of mine started facing this problem yesterday night: when she browses through her Instagram stories, the video plays at a slower rate than normal, however the sound is totally fine. She went ahead and checked the gallery as well - same problem there. In TikTok though, there are no issues at all.

As she did not provide any more information (she is not tech savvy at all) here is the info that I know about her phone: it's a Huawei Y5 2018, with Android 8.

I searched online about this, but I didn't come up with anything related to Android. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The latest version(s) of Instagram app seems to be very buggy. We have a large numbers of users complaining about different problems. May be the video problem is just another bug of the recent version.

Comment: @Robert Yes, IG might be buggy. But it also happens in the Gallery app. How is this explained?

Comment: @Robert Nevermind, she just messaged me saying it's OK now (she maybe deleted the cache). Should I delete the question to avoid a reputation drop?